# Pick schema of key in Joi schema

Tags: joi

If I have a JOI schema

```
const OBJ1 = Joi.object({
  foo: Joi.number(), 
  bar: Joi.string().pattern(/abc/)
});
```

And then I want to have a second schema `OBJ2` which uses the same `/abc/` schema as the `bar` property in `OBJ1` for another property:

```
const OBJ2 = Joi.object({
  baz: Joi.string().pattern(/abc/)}
);
```

Does the API then support picking the schema for the key `bar` out of `OBJ1` instead of definining it again in `OBJ2`?

I realize I can do the following:

```
const ABC = Joi.string().pattern(/abc/);
const OBJ1 = Joi.object({
  foo: Joi.number(), 
  bar: ABC
});
const OBJ2 = Joi.object({
  baz: ABC
});
```

But what I'm after is something like:

```
const OBJ1 = Joi.object({
  foo: Joi.number(), 
  bar: Joi.string().pattern(/abc/)
});
const OBJ2 = Joi.object({
  baz: OBJ1.pick('bar')
});
```

But I wasn't able to find anything like this in the JOI API reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself: `extract(key)`:

```
const OBJ2 = Joi.object({
  baz: OBJ1.extract('bar')
});
```

Simple as that, but hard to find in the docs, apparently.